# Different values from subset of a table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two tables,

[image: company]

[image: shops]

and I want to know in the company table the number of different countries per company.

I don`t know how to count the different values for only certain rows.

The solution should be without VBA.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Pivot Tables.  The reason being is you don't have to worry about formulas and the Pivot does all the hard work for you.  If you update the data all you need to do is click Update on your pivot table and bam, all done.

Basically you would highlight all the information in table 2 and do `Insert -> Pivot Table`

Leave the options as default (Select a table) and (New Worksheet) then click OK.

Drag `Company ID` to the `Rows` block.  Drag the `Country ID` to the `Columns` block and again to the `Values` block.

Right click on the `Country ID` under the `Values` block and select `Value Field Settings`

Change the `Summarize value field by` from `Sum` to `Count` and click `OK`

See the screenshot.  This is what you will get.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Use this array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10=A2,1/COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$10,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$10,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10,A2)))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Sheet1 is my data sheet:

[image]

So on sheet two I place the formula in C2 and copy down:

[image]

Comment: This is called an Array Formula (AKA CSE formula) if anyone needed a reference:  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7