# MS Excel - I wish to count unique values based on a parent column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I am very new to Excel. I need some help in counting unique values in each of three columns (considering them only one at a time) with respect to a parent column (the first one (A) in the image). Can you please help me out out?
Thanks!

Edit: If I do a pivot table it doesn't give me count of individual columns but the final column.

**Source Data:**

[image]

**Result Data after transformation:**

[image]

Source

```
A   B   C   D
p   d   g   k
p   e   g   k
q   d   h   k
q   f   h   o
r   d   h   o
r   e   i   m
r   f   h   m
s   d   i   n
s   d   i   o
s   f   i   o
```

Result

```
A   B   C   D
p   2   1   1
q   2   1   2
r   3   2   2
s   2   1   2
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: See my answer [HERE](http://superuser.com/questions/1077526/different-values-from-subset-of-a-table/1077539#1077539)

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do from your example.

Answer (score 0):

We build a list of the column **A** uniques and put it in column **E** and then perform a set of loops to count the uniques in the other columns:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    Dim c As Collection, v As Variant
    Dim M As Long, j As Long, rc As Long
    Dim K As Long

    Columns("A:A").Copy Columns("E:E")
    Range("E:E").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

    rc = Rows.Count
    M = Cells(rc, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    N = Cells(rc, "E").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To N
        v = Cells(i, "E").Text
            For K = 2 To 4
                Set c = Nothing
                Set c = New Collection
                For j = 1 To M
                    If v = Cells(j, "A").Text Then
                        On Error Resume Next
                            c.Add Cells(j, K).Text, CStr(Cells(j, K).Text)
                        On Error GoTo 0
                    End If
                Next j
                Cells(i, K + 4).Value = c.Count
            Next K
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]